# How to Upgrade Pinax for Django 2.0

Tags: django, pinax, django-2.0

I am trying to upgrade my django project to Django 2.0, and I have read the release notes and read several blog posts about what to change, but nothing addresses my problem so far, which relates to the package `pinax`:

```
      File "/Users/marlo/miniconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.6/site-
        packages/pinax/eventlog/models.py", line 13, in 
        class Log(models.Model):
      File "/Users/marlo/miniconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pinax/eventlog/models.py", line 22, in Log
        content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True)
    TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Are there any fixes for this yet?

Comment: You might need to update your library. "The on_delete argument for ForeignKey and OneToOneField is now required in models and migrations" - [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#features-removed-in-2-0)

Comment: @BojanKogoj It's true that this was missing `on_delete`, but pinax is a package, not a file in my project, so I shouldn't be changing the code.  It turned out that we needed to update `pinax-eventlog`:  `pip install -U pinax-eventlog`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to update `pinax-eventlog` to latest to pick up Django 2.0 compatibility, which is currently `2.0.3`.

In your project's `requirements.txt` file add:

`pinax-eventlog==2.0.3`

So when you run `pip install -r requirements.txt` the right version will install.  Otherwise, you can just run `pip install pinax-eventlog==2.0.3`.

Comment: Thanks, that ended up being the issue!  If you could update your answer to include the syntax for that (or link to a source with the info), I'll select it as the best answer.

Comment: Edits Done.  Thanks!